# Build forms in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

I need build forms in Laravel Blade. I am very beginner in Laravel. I use in my project Laravel 7.
I found component: https://www.bgaze.fr/bootstrap-formv

It's ok?

I want build this form in Bootstram 4:

```
<form method="POST"
      @if($page ?? false) action="{{ route('page.update', ['id' => $page->id ?? null]) }}"
      @else action="{{ route('page.store') }}" @endif class="form form-horizontal form-bordered">
    @if($page ?? false) @method('PUT') @endif
    {{ csrf_field()  }}

    <div class="box-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title">Tytuł strony tekstowej*</label>
            <input id="title" type="text" name="title" required="required" maxlength="155" class="form-control"
                   placeholder="Wpisz tytuł strony tekstowej*" value="{{ $page->title ?? old('title') }}">
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Treść strony tekstowej</label>
            <textarea class="form-control summernote" name="content" rows="3"
                      placeholder="Wpisz treść strony tekstowej">{{ $page->content ?? old('content') }}</textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group size-200">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Wpis aktywny</label>
            <label class="switch ">
                <input name="enable" value="1"
                       @if(!empty($page) && $page->enable == '1') checked="checked"
                       @endif  type="checkbox" class="primary" id="switch1"/>
                <span class="switcher round"></span>
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="box-footer">
            <button type="submit"
                    class="btn btn-primary">Save
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

How can I make this form in https://www.bgaze.fr/bootstrap-form ? 
Could I have some example of this form, please? I would like to build my remaining forms based on this example

Please help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **laravelcollective/html** instead of **bgaze/bootstrap-form**

Example:

```
{!! Form::open(array('route'=>array('users.create'), 'method'=>'post')) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
       {!! Form::label('name', 'Name:',['class'=>'control-label']) !!}
       {!! Form::text('name', '', array('id' => 'name','class'=>'form-control')) !!}
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success">Save</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: thank you very much. How can I write this inputL value="{{ $page->keywords ?? old('keywords') }}" ? (data from DB or OLD values)? Can you show me checkbox and select?

Comment: `{!! Form::model($user, array('route'=>array('users.update')'method'=>'post')) !!}                   
 {!! Form::text('name', old('name'), array('id' => 'name','class'=>'form-control')) !!}  {!! Form::close() !!}
`

Comment: @traffske For select is example `Form::select('size', ['L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'], 'S')` and checkbox `Form::checkbox('name', 'value', 1)`

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do:

- make sure that **[composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/)** is installed on your system
- run the command (in installation section)

  `composer require bgaze/bootstrap-form`
- that's it you can now use codes as the demo and copy codes from examples in the page

Code

```
@open(['novalidate' => true])
  @text('login')
  @email('email')
  @checkbox('remember_me', null, 1, null, ['switch' => true, 'inline' => true])
  @submit('Login')
@close
```